# Can you open the instagram app on mobile and also load an image to create a story?

Tags: javascript, mobile, instagram

I want to create a function that opens the Instagram app on mobile and also loads an image into the page to create a story. When the story loads, it shouldn't immediately be posted, the user still has to press the button to post the story to their account.

This is the script that I have right now to open the Instagram app:

```
function openInstagramApp() {
  var isInstagramAppInstalled = navigator.userAgent.match(/instagram/i);

  if (isInstagramAppInstalled) {
    window.location.href = "instagram://";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "https://www.instagram.com/";
  }
}
```